# NetBeans IDE Connection Wizard and java beans with constrained properties

Tags: java, netbeans, javabeans

I am working on a small beans example and I am trying to connect a bean with a constrained property to a second bean. I do not know what to put in the NetBeans IDE Connection Wizard and cannot find this complexity in the java tutorials. Does someone know what to do? I have tried to add a property listener but cannot get it right. Below I will show you my source and listener beans.

// SOURCE BEAN

```
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.beans.*;

/**
 * Bean with a constrained property "counter".
 */
public class ConstrainedBean
        extends JComponent
        implements Serializable
{

    public int counter = 0;

    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs =
        new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private VetoableChangeSupport vcs =
        new VetoableChangeSupport(this);

    private String title;

    public int getInteger() {
        return counter;
    }


    public void setInteger(int i) throws PropertyVetoException {

        int old = this.counter;
        this.vcs.fireVetoableChange("counter", old, i);

        this.counter = i;
        this.pcs.firePropertyChange("counter", old, i);
    }

    public void
    addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void
    removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void
    addVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener) {
        vcs.addVetoableChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void
    removeVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener) {
        vcs.removeVetoableChangeListener(listener);
    }


    protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        this.title = Integer.toString(counter);

        g.setColor( getForeground() );

        int style = Font.PLAIN;

        int fontSize = 50;

        Font font = new Font ("Arial", style , fontSize);

        g.setFont(font);

        int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        System.out.println(height);

        if ( this.title != null )
            g.drawString(this.title, 0, height );

       }
   }
```

// LISTENER BEAN

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.beans.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

/**
 * Bean with a simple property "counter".
 */
public class CounterBean
        extends JComponent
        implements Serializable
{

    public int counter = 0;

    public String title;

      public int getInteger() {
        return counter;
    }


    public void setInteger(int i) {
        counter = i;
    }

    public class VetoChangeListener implements VetoableChangeListener {

    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
                        throws PropertyVetoException
    {

        Object oldc=evt.getOldValue();
        Object newc=evt.getNewValue();
        String s=evt.getPropertyName();

        int sourcecounter = ((Integer)newc).intValue();

        if ((sourcecounter <-5) | (sourcecounter >5))
        {throw new PropertyVetoException("out of bounds",evt);}
        else
        {counter=sourcecounter;}


    }

    }


    protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        this.title = Integer.toString(counter);

        g.setColor( getForeground() );

        int style = Font.PLAIN;

        int fontSize = 25;

        Font font = new Font ("Arial", style , fontSize);

        g.setFont(font);

        int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        System.out.println(height);

        if ( this.title != null )
            g.drawString(this.title, 0, height );

       }
   }
```

//

Any help would be gratefully accepted. This is the most complicated of the property types.
ps NetBeans 5.5.1!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple. The top level class in the listener bean must implement
VetoableChangeListener. When this is the case, the options in the NetBeans Connection Wizard will make sense. Please note that the listener bean does not currently display its counter
variable correctly but I suspect a repaint should do the trick. In my setup, "+1" and "-1"
buttons are wired to the source bean.